# How could I grant www-data write permissions to a Docker volume with SUBUIDs/SUBGIDs?

Tags: permissions, docker

I am using SUBUIDs and SUBGIDs when running docker, so the file permissions in the docker volume are the following:

```
$> ls -la /var/lib/docker/231072.231072/volumes/docroot/_data/some.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 232071 232071 56 Jul 20 14:23 /var/lib/docker/231072.231072/volumes/docroot/_data/some.php
```

Then I'm starting the container with the following command:

```
docker run -d -v thevolume:/var/www/html container
```

If I plan to use that volume for read-only purposes, it works fine, but what if `www-data` needs to have write permissions? How could I grant write permissions to the volume?

I know I could `chown www-data` on the host/volume if I did not use SUBUIDs/SUBGIDs. With SUBUIDs/SUBGIDs this is not so easy anymore - the only way I can imagine is to `docker exec -it container /bin/bash` into the container and run `chown -R www-data` from there, which would change the SUBUIDs in the volume, but isn't there any other more sophisticated way to do that?